# 2D FDTD Transmission calculation

Tags: python

I've implemented a 2D FDTD algorithm to solve a waveguide. I'm tring to calculate the transmission but I get weird results.

Initially I was just taking the FFT of th incident field and the transmitted and divding them, but I get a graph with peaks and noise.
I recently came across a method that asked to implement a poynting vector but I'm still struggling to get the results. This is how I code my poynitng vector:

1/(2*eta_0) *np.real((j*Eyz[1:Nx,1:Nz]*(Hx[1:Nx,1:Nz] + Hx[1:Nx,0:Nz-1]))/2)

I have source at Eyz and Hx

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.